Class market with @Immutable or @Stable is still unstable
I am learning about stability and going over this blog post  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8 while locally trying to replicate some of the scenarios.
So imagine I have this:

ScalingLazyColumn(columnState = scrollState) {
            item {
                ContactRow(
                    snacks = listOf(
                        Snack("Peanut", setOf("alergic", "sweet")),
                        Snack("Chips", setOf("salty", "bier friendly")),
                        Snack("Sticks", setOf("salty", "bier friendly"))
                    ),
                    contact = Contact("Gregory", "123345")
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ContactRow(snacks: List<Snack>, contact: Contact) {
    var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column {
        Row(modifier) {
            ContactDetails(contact)
            ToggleButton(selected, onToggled = {
                selected = !selected
            })
        }
        HighlightedSnacks(snacks)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ContactDetails(contact: Contact) {
    val modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.DarkGray)
        .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
    Column {
        Text(modifier = modifier, text = contact.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Text(modifier = modifier, text = contact.number, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ToggleButton(selected: Boolean, onToggled: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Switch(checked = selected, onCheckedChange = { onToggled(it) })
}


@Composable
fun HighlightedSnacks(list: List<Snack>) {
    Column {
        list.forEach {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
                text = "${it.name} - ${it.tags}",
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}

data class Contact(val name: String, val number: String)

@Immutable // <---------------- mark it as immutable
data class Snack(
    val name: String,
    val tags: Set<String> = emptySet()
)

I run the compiler reports and initially the HighlightedSnacks appeared as unsable because of the tags set in the Snack data class. So far so good. But then I market Snack data class with @Immutable (as well as @Stable later), and to my surprize the Snack class continues to be unstable. I also can see it being recomposed everytime the toggle is changed.
Why is it so?
Setting the @Immutable annotation to the data class should have market the parent composable as stable, and thus skip recompositions.

EDIT: I tried instead to use val tags: ImmutableSet<String> = persistentSetOf(). Now the tags field is market as stable in the report. But to my surprize, when I check the layout inspection it is still being recomposed. How come?

OK, I should have continued to read the blog post because that was expected. The reason it was still market as unstable was that HighlightedSnacks was accepting a List type as parameter which is inherently unstable. The solution is to use as parameter ImmutableList or wrap the set into a data class annotated with @Immutable and use that.
